# Is there a way to code to cause Windows to switch user?

Tags: windows, vba, excel

I have created a macro that needs to run at a specific time from a workbook unfortunately at that time it is also shift change and the user sometimes logs off for the next user that is going to use the workstation and the macro will not run, since it closes Excel.

I have a macro to prevent closing of the workbook until after shift change but I would like to know if there is a function I can call that will bring up the Switch User Screen. That way the workbook will stay open and do its thing then close and log that user off.

I was able to find the LockWorkStation function in the User32.dll but I am not familiar with these libraries and don't know if there is a Switch User Function.

Comment: Switching the user essentially means that the current user is being logged off and a new user needs to logon to Windows on a computer. As soon as a user logs off all programs open and running for that particular user are being closed and stop running. Hence, you could merely get a macro to do "its thing" and then log off the current user to display the "login screen" for Windows again. But that's it.

Comment: That is not the case if you have fast user switching enabled.

Comment: In this case you might want to have a look at the following website: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/fdfaf619-547b-487c-8608-229783069fed/how-to-manage-fast-user-switching-on-domain-joined-computers?forum=w7itprogeneral Yet, you should be aware that this solution does not support computers which are part of a domain as FUS cannot be enabled for domain accounts: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/280758

Comment: Furthermore, Microsoft notes that FUS [...] can cause other running instances of the application to behave in an unpredictable manner [...]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776893%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Just want to make you aware of these possible pitfalls.